# How to create iText PDF with CMY colors only

Tags: pdf, colors, pdf-generation, itext

I need to create pdfs with iText (for the moment, other lib suggestions are appreciated) in the CMY colorspace. It's not CMYK:

All colors and black should be converted to CMY only so that the black plate is empty when saving my created PDF. I know, black would look some sort of brown, but I have to requirement to not use any black plate for this pdfs.

Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

(PS: this is like [need-help-answers-on-pdf-color-seperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532089/need-help-answers-on-pdf-color-seperation), but instead of converting pdfs, I now ask about creation. But if anyone has an answer to the linked question that would also help!)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go about this.  First, you need to decide how you're going to represent your colors...

1. CMYK where the 'k' is always zero
2. Device-N colorspace, with three color channels.  "Colorants" is the term I believe.

Then you need to use iText's color objects, and make sure every single color attribute is set to either one of your colors, or to null (which translates to 'not drawn' in iText-ville).  There will be a lot of default values you'll need to hunt down and replace.

You might want to hack on iText's source a bit to help you, specifically `PdfContentByte`.  There are a couple different options.

1. Find all the places where it sets the color, and throw an exception save when its using one of your colors (CMKY-with-no-K or Device-N-where-N-is-3).
2. Much harder:  In all those places you're throwing, TRANSLATE the color into the equivalent in your color space instead.  Gray-scale to CMY-No-K shouldn't be all that hard, but good RGB->CMYK translation is *at least* as much art as science...

And if you including any images that aren't CMY-no-K to begin with, you'd HAVE to translate them.  No getting around it.  And if you're translating some colors, you might as well go with at least a partial version of #2 above.